# Who or whom in this statement?

Tags: grammar, whom

What is the proper pronoun in the following sentence?

> There is no concept of leadership beyond (whomever/whoever) happens to be most experienced on a given team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **whoever.** Since the person in question is the subject of the verb "happens," the nominative is correct. See [this page from Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/who-whom) on who/whom for details.

Furthermore, as the above article notes, "whom" is slowly being replaced by "who," so one could argue that one should use "whoever" regardless of context.

Incidentally, "beyond" may be the wrong word here. [MacMillan defines it](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/beyond_1) in this sense as "except," which does not work in context.